# How do i login with selenium and scrape text with scrapy

Tags: selenium, scrapy, headless-browser

I'm trying to login to the wall street journal website using selenium and then scrape some data about a specific article using scrapy. However, my code doesn't seem to work as I don't know how to combine the 2. Is there any way I can do this? I have put the **individual (not combined)** code for the two

My scrapy spider (without selenium)

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class NewsSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'news_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['wsj.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.wsj.com/articles/fed-deliberates-how-and-when-to-roll-out-more-economic-support-11595410201?mod=hp_lead_pos6']

def parse(self, response):

    data = response.css('#article_sector')
    
    author_list = data.xpath("//div[@class='byline article__byline']//button[@class='author-button']/text()").extract()
    author_length = len(author_list)

    time = data.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix byline-wrap']//time[@class='timestamp article__timestamp flexbox__flex--1']/text()").extract()

    for i in range(0,author_length):
        yield{'Author name': ''.join(author_list[i]), 'Time': ''.join(time[0])}
```

My selenium autologin code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'emailid@gmail.com'
passwordStr = 'passwd'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SA0R01ubWFmQUkwemNDc1JPaUQtR1JBNDZZVEs3S0xLRaN0aWTZIE50X1BYRkFnN0FvamNrTmhmNGJNb2NXdUdYeEFqWFNxo2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid%20tags%20prts&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=b97014df-1e52-4173-b331-84d7bf3d5215&ui_locales=en-us-x-wsj-83-2&ns=prod%2Faccounts-wsj&savelogin=on#!/signin'))

# fill in username and hit the next button
username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')

username.send_keys(usernameStr)
#nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
#nextButton.click()

password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signInButton.click()

drive.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried using scrapy.FormRequest for the login procedure ? rather than resorting to selenium to do that ? There are a couple of ways of using selenium in scrapy. 1) Just putting your selenium content within scrapy but being mindful of the response and the functions. 2) Using a selenium download middleware like scrapy_selenium 3) scrapy-splash 4) Creating your own download middleware that uses the selenium package to handle parts of the code that need selenium. Stackoverflow is littered with how to handle dynamic content with scrapy.

Comment: Also worth looking at Check out https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html for general approaches to handle dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give specific advice as we can't do the login procedure for you! But some general advice is this.

1. Consider using the scrapy.FormRequest to do the login procedure before turning to selenium. Far more efficient than using browser activity. See video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lo3aswJ7lzw) for the basics, another article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scrapy-this-is-how-to-successfully-login-with-ease-ea980e2c5901) docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login).
2. Look at the scrapy documentation with regard to dynamic content [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html)
   This will give you an overview of the steps to handling dynamic content. I will say generally speaking selenium should be thought of as a last resort. It's pretty inefficient when doing larger scale scraping.
3. If you are consider adding in the selenium package into your script. This might be the lower barrier of entry to getting your script working but not necessarily that efficient. At the end of the day scrapy is a framework but there is a lot of flexibility in adding in 3rd party packages. The spider scripts are just a python class importing the scrapy architecture in the background. As long as you're mindful of the response and translating some of the selenium to work with scrapy, you should be able to input selenium into your scripts. I would this solution is probably the least efficient though.
4. Consider using scrapy-splash, splash pre-renders the page and allows for you to add in javascript execution. Docs are [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) and a good article from scrapinghub [here](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash)

5. Scrapy-selenium is a package with a custom scrapy downloader middleware that allows you to do selenium actions and execute javascript. Docs [here](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) You'll need to have a play around to get the login in procedure from this, it doesn't have the same level of detail as the selenium package itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! I will try the options as provided by you.